# vim mapping ctrl-` or <c-`> to <c-w>w

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, keymapping

I tried

```
inoremap <c-`> <c-w>w
```

and various combination, but nothing seems to work. Is cntrl-` already mapped?

Using Lubuntu 64 bit 16.04 : lxterminal
Attempted cntrl-v cntrl-` to find the character but nothing shows up.

FYI: I am attempting to make sure I can do same thing with my VSCode editor.

Answer (score 5):

In a typical terminal, <kbd>*control*</kbd><kbd>**`**</kbd> is an ASCII `NUL` (zero), which vim will not map.  Using `cat -v` to make the result visible, you'd likely see

```
^@
```

which is a single character...

You'd have the same behavior for a few other keys which typically produce a `NUL`, e.g., <kbd>*control*</kbd><kbd>*space*</kbd>, or <kbd>*control*</kbd><kbd>**`@`**</kbd> (really!)

Comment: `<C-Space>` worked for my use-case, but you are correct in that it also gets triggered for other key combinations like Ctrl+Space (the spacebar). If you can live with that, then it is an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can't map anything to `Ctrl-Backtick` because Vim won't recognize it no matter what you do.

Find another key combination.

Answer (score 1):

As @romainl and @Thomas Dickey pointed out, you can't do this in terminal vim.
If you want this is in VSCode, just add this to `keybindings.json` and add this to the editable pane.

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
  { "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.navigateEditorGroups" },
]
```

This will work as VSCode doesn't have the same problem of interpreting <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> as your terminal.

Also, it might not be a good idea to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> as it is already being used for toggling integrated terminal

> ```
> ⌃`    Toggle Integrated Terminal workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal
> ```

[How to modify keybinding for VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

> Is cntrl-` already mapped?

No. Even if a key combination is mapped, you can override it in vim.

> Attempted cntrl-v cntrl-` to find the character but nothing shows up.

Now you know why

Comment: { "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus"},
    { "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup", "when": "terminalFocus"},
Thanks - actually above is what I had already in VSCode. And that's default on VSCode. And I was just trying to mach on neovim side.

Comment: @quantt: From your question, I understood that you wanted to do this in VSCode. Do upvote if any information was useful

Comment: Actually u missread. I am already doing it on VSCode. So, I wanted make neovim same as VSCode. Sure. May be I should have been more clear. Thanks anyway,

Answer (score 0):

Well, as two other answers indicated. I could NOT find the key combo & I do NOT think I will; however, when using nyaoVim the key combos do work. So, it's just terminal issue.
A bit of pain to install but now everything pretty much works!